# Missing 4.7 reference assemblies in hosted VSTS build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I received the following error message in my VSTS build step when trying to build my Visual Studio 2017 project.

> "The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7"

How can I get VSTS to build my VS2017 project properly? I have tried pointing out specific msbuild versions, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to change the **agent queue** setting from **Hosted** to **Hosted VS2017**.

Like this:

[image: To Hosted VS2017]

I found this solution in this thread, there's more info there:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/83942/vsts-still-does-not-support-net-v47.html